# 'snakeviz' command not recognized despite successful installation in Python 3.8

Tags: python, profile, snakeviz

I am using python 3.8 and have installed the `snakeviz` module.

I can (successfully) generate the profile of my program by running the command:

```
> python -m cProfile -o program.prof temp_profile.py
```

But then when I try to visualize the profile using `snakeviz program.prof` i get the error:

```
snakeviz : The term 'snakeviz' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...
```

I've tried rebooting PyCharm, and re-intsalling `snakeviz`; but the problem remains.